# Java conditional Statement Understanding

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

```java
package ClassTest3;


public class IdentifyPosiibleWords {

    public static String identifyWords(String input1, String input2) {
        int i, j;
            input1 = input1.toUpperCase();
            input2 = input2.toUpperCase();
            String word = "", res = "";
            String[] words = input2.split(":");
            System.out.println(input1.length());
            for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                word = words[i];
                if (input1.length() == word.length()) {
                    for (j = 0; j < input1.length(); j++) {
                        if (input1.charAt(j) != '_' && input1.charAt(j) != word.charAt(j)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (j == input1.length()) {
                        res = res + word + ":";
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return res.length() == 0 ? "ERROR-009" : res.substring(0, res.length() - 1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String input1 = "Fi_er";
        String input2 = "Fever:filer:Filter: Fixer:fiber:fibre:tailor:offer";
        
        String output = identifyWords(input1, input2);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}
```

This program has no error, the only this i uploaded here i have a doubt in this code

see the line 22 : `if (j == input1.length())` this inner nested loop update the `j` in line 7 but at the end of the matching word found, `j` will be `4` and how it will pass the `input1.length` that is `5`.

someone please explain it to me.

Comment: Why do you think `j == 4` at the end of the loop when `input1.length() == 5`. Look at the loop condition. What value does `j` need to have for that to be false, allowing the loop to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the loop exited, `j < input1.length()` is false.

However, it has just been incremented by one.

Therefore, at this point, assuming you entered the loop body at least once:

`j == input1.length()` is true.

Comment: but the for loop will stop the increment when the `j < input1.length()` is false right?

Comment: In a `for` loop, the update body is executed /before/ the condition expression is checked.  The last increment that causes `j` to be equal to `input1.length()` will absolutely occur.